# Evaluating $\int_0^{+\infty}|e^{-x}\sin(x)|dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $$I_t=\int_0^t|e^{-x}\sin(x)|dx.$$ I am interested in finding $$I_{+\infty}=\lim_{t\to+\infty}I_t.$$
A possibility related integral is $$I_{+\infty}^\prime=\lim_{k\to+\infty}I_k^\prime=\lim_{k\to+\infty}\int_0^ke^{-x}\sin(x)dx=\lim_{k\to+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(1-e^{-k}\left(\sin(k)+\cos(k)\right)\right)\right)=\frac{1}{2}.$$ I do not know how to evaluate $I_{+\infty}.$ However, I tried Wolfram Alpha, and according to it, $I_{+\infty}=\frac{1+e^\pi}{2e^\pi-2}.$ How to arrive at this result?

Comment: you should be able to evaluate $\int_0^k e^{-x}\sin(x)\mathrm{d}x$ by partially integrating twice and solving the resulting equation

Comment: @student91, yes, and I did that in my post. My question is about $I_{+\infty},$ and not $I_{+\infty}^\prime.$ Thanks, though.

Comment: Oops, I was confused by the "A possibly related integral is ..., I do not know how to evaluate this integral", have a nice day!

Comment: @AnneBauval, it does. When I looked up this question on MSE, I didn't put the absolute value sign on $\sin(x)$ alone, and hence the linked question didn't show up. Thanks.

Comment: @student91, you're right, that is confusing. I'll edit that out so future viewers don't get confused.